# Android Studio - EditText.addTextChangedListener not working

Tags: java, android, fragment, addtextchangedlistener

I have an application that I had implemented Fragment Pager Adapter for swiping pages using fragment. Then, on the fragment, it have a EditText and a TextView. I want to implement  **EditText.addTextChangedListener** into the fragment, so at MainActivity.java

```
package testing.com.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import layout.page1;
import layout.page2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager()));

}


public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {
            return new page1();
        } else 
            return new page2();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}

}
```

My fragment.java

```
package layout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import testing.com.testing.R;


public class page1 extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    EditText text;
    TextView textv;
    text = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.p1Name);
    textv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);

    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            textv.setText(s);
        }
    });
}

}
```

But it doesn't work, I get error on TextWatcher, error: cannot find symbol class TextWatcher, Execution failed for task ':appcompileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Can anyone please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `R.id.p1Name` and `R.id.textView` in your fragment's layout

Inside your fragment in `onActivityCreated(...)` method get the reference to the edittext and set the addTextChangedListener over there.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

 text = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.p1Name);
 textv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);

text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        textv.setText(s);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying! At my fragment.java, I pasted the codes and added 

EditText text;
TextView textv;

But there's error for TextWatcher (Cannot resolve symbol 'TextWatcher')

Comment: No, this show up
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: can you share the complete code for fragment and activity? to check what exactly are you doing.